# Can we change the Application Window TaskBar icon at run time in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

My application functions like outlook. When I minimize the application it will minimized at system tray and when maximized the window taskbar icon is also shown.

I can change the system tray icon at run time ,but can I also change the Window Taskbar icon ( Application icon embedded into the application at build time) at runtime ?

Answer (score 4):

```
this.Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("..."));
```

Here `this` is `Window` object.